# MySQL - Export data with desired form from table

Tags: php, mysql

The story is that I received a table with the following structure

| Item | Attribute | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | AttrName1 | Value1 |
| ABC123 | AttrName2 | Value2 |
| ABC123 | AttrName3 | Value3 |
| DEF456 | AttrName1 | Value1 |
| DEF456 | AttrName2 | Value2 |
| DEF456 | AttrName3 | Value3 |

I want to export to CSV with the better form to do import, following by

| Item | AttrName1 | AttrName2 | AttrName3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |
| DEF456 | Value1 | Value2 | Value3 |

Is there any SQL statement that can do this? Or is an idea to implement a short script to handle this? Thanks

Comment: Are there always exactly 3 attributes for each item?

Comment: It's dynamic! Could be hundreds!

Comment: Suppose you have the table with "hundreds" columns and rows for each item - what are you gonna do with it afterwards?

Comment: We have a script to import values to the database with the logic that uses the format of the desired form as I have mentioned! The logic of the script is unchangeable. That is my purpose :)

Comment: ok, so basically you need CSV with rows like like: item#1, value of AttrName1, value of AttrName2, (empty <item has no AttrName3), value of AttrName4, ..., value of AttrNameN ?

Comment: Correct! And included the headers also!

Comment: this source data are in MySQL database/table or in CSV file? you want to run it as PHP script from command line?

Comment: This source data is in the MySQL database! I prefer SQL statement to run it!